# Trouble getting count with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query the following XDOC to verify how many elements contain a value starting with “in.”  I expect a return of four but it always returns one???

```
    string xml = @"<Programs><ProgramName>in.sy.prog.n.r1.test-package</ProgramName><ProgramName>un.sy.nopr.n.r1.test-package</ProgramName><ProgramName>sr.pt.mang.n.r1.test-package</ProgramName><ProgramName>in.sy.prog.n.r1.test-packageENCAP</ProgramName><ProgramName>in.sy.prog.n.r1.test-packageENCAPTwo</ProgramName><ProgramName>in.sy.prog.n.r1.test-package2</ProgramName></Programs>";
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var programNameCount =
    (from el in doc.Descendants("Programs")
    where el.Element("ProgramName").Value.ToLower().StartsWith("in.")
    select el.Element("ProgramName")).Count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the count of `ProgramName` not `Programs`

```
var programNameCount =  (from el in docx.Descendants("ProgramName")
                         where el.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("in.")
                         select el)
                        .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need `el.Element` in either the projection nor the filter. Furthermore, you want to count the Descendants of ProgramName, whose value starts with `in.` and not the Descendants of Programs.

```
var programNameCount = (from el in doc.Descendants("ProgramName")
                        where el.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("in.")
                        select el).Count();
```